# Get value from a dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c#, string, dll, load, return

### Simple question:

How to retrieve a string thats located in a dynamically loaded Dll?

### Detail:Case:

I have 2 projects, one Dll & one "main" form.
The Dll gets loaded as a control in a panel on the main form.

mainForm:

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Plugin Files|*.dll";
            if (DialogResult.OK == ofd.ShowDialog())
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(ofd.FileName);
                Type type = assembly.GetType("FormDLL.Form1");
                Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                //form.ShowDialog(); // Or Application.Run(form)

                form.TopLevel = false;
                panel1.Controls.Add(form);
                form.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                form.Show();
            }
```

/

### What i'm trying to do

I'm trying to retrieve a string from the Dll.. like so

```
namespace FormDLL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string dllTitle = "DllTab1";
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    }
}
```

mainForm

```
button1.text = (load the Dll somehow).dllTitle
```

note, I want the user to be able to just drop Dll's in a folder, so I think adding the Dll as a referens in VS is not a option, I guess.

Comment: Use an interface that describes a dllTitle property, implement it in your dll, cast and call in the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try this:

```
Type myType = form.GetType();
IList<FieldInfo> fields = new List<FieldInfo>(myType.GetFields());

object fValue;
foreach (FieldInfo f in fields)
{
    if(f.Name == "dllTitle")
    {
        fValue = f.GetValue(form);
        break;
     }
}
```

Also you can use LinQ instead of foreach.